# ubuntu 12.04 server can not reboot on its own after reinstallation

Tags: 12.04, boot, server

We reinstalled the ubuntu 12.04 server after power outrage. After reinstallation, the server can not reboot on its own. Here is the current manual reboot procedure:

1. After reboot now, the server powers up. After boot up menu (top 2 are boot into regular or recovery mode), the server goes directly into blank screen and hung (keystroke does not matter).
2. Hit control-alt-delete to restart again. This time the server will pass the bootup menu and stops at attached scsi disk. After hitting enter, the server goes into prompt initramfs. After typing exit, the server will go to the login screen.
3. login.

What's wrong with the ubuntu 12.04 server and how to fix it? Thanks for help.

/var/log/boot.log

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--ibm-root: clean, 101595/8634368 files, 1177251/34523136 blocks
/dev/sda1: clean, 230/124496 files, 40645/248832 blocks
 * Starting CUPS printing spooler/server                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting load fallback graphics devices                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping load fallback graphics devices                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping cold plug devices                                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping log initial device creation                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping save udev log and update rules                               [ OK ]
 * Stopping Userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
 * Stopping OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting OpenSSH server                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping Mount network filesystems                                    [ OK ]
 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay                                          [ OK ]
 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf                            [ OK ]
 * Stopping set sysctls from /etc/sysctl.conf                            [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                                                  [ OK ]
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility                        [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility                              [ OK ]
 * Starting crash report submission daemon                               [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation                            [ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

*What is your skill level?*

*How detailed instructions do you need?*

***Have you tried? :***

(1.) Check RAM.

(2.) Try **Recovery Mode**

(3.) Boot from startup-DVD or -USB, and 'attempt repair'.

---

Is is possible 'power outage' damaged CPU/motherboard? Is it no longer stable?

( a long RAM test cycle will pick that up. )

Comment: Probably need detail instructions. It is possible that there is hardware damage after power outage. Before reinstallation, tried to bootup from the system CD and attempt repair a few times and did not help. Also tried to sync again the RAID array (mirror) and it went fine. will try memory test with the system CD to see what it finds.

Comment: Memory test passes without error.

Comment: One thing a little odd. When scanning disk for defects with system CD, only CD-ROM gets scanned. No HD!